# Finding the coefficients of multiplication of multiple polynomials

Tags: polynomials

I want to find the coefficients of the following polynomial

$$(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\cdots(x-n),$$ $n$ can vary up to $100000$.

Is there any general form to find the coefficient of the above polynomial?

Comment: Look up Stirling numbers of the first kind.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: http://oeis.org/A094638

Comment: The coefficient of $x^0$ is $(-1)^n\,n!$, I'd like to see you computing this for $n=100000$.